# Why return null for return null; }

Tags: android, listview

I don't understand why return null in the following code. please help

```
public Crime getCrime(UUID id){
   for (Crime crime: mCrimes){
      if (crime.getId().equals(id)){
        return crime;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: By the way this android

Comment: If no `crime` satisfies the condition `crime.getId().equals(id)` then return `null`

Comment: crime id would not match with any id in entire array so default it was  return null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to imagine what would happen if `return null;` is removed. After that, you'll understand why it is neccessary to put that there.

In the method, you loop through `mCrimes` to check if one of the crimes' id is equal to the parameter `id`. If it is, return that crime. Now what if nothing in `mCrimes` satisfies the condition? Code execution will simply break out of the loop and... do nothing?

We can't do nothing because we have declared the method to return a `Crime`. We can't just leave the method without returning anything! We must return *some* value. Since the method returns a crime with a particular id, if the id passed in does not correspond to any crime, we should *return nothing* to signify that there is no crime with this id.

Since we want to return nothing if this happens, we write

```
return null;
```

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Its because if List/Array doesn't contain passed id then it doesn't return from condition inside loop and comes next to loop end.

Then at last method needs something to return.

That's why it returns null.

Comment: Makes sense now Thank you